# Dynamically nesting group by inside Collector

Tags: java, collectors

I have this piece of code which is working fine:

```
Collector nestedCollector = Collectors.groupingBy((Map map) -> map.get("PROCESS_NAME"),
    Collectors.groupingBy((Map map) -> map.get("PROCESS_INSTANCE")));
```

However, I can't use fixed map keys in my code (PROCESS_NAME, PROCESS_INSTANCE).
What I need is to pass the list of keys via parameter and generate a nested collector, something like this:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList();
keys.add("PROCESS_NAME");
keys.add("PROCESS_INSTANCE");
keys.add("...some other key...");

Collector nestedCollector= Collectors.groupingBy(...nested groupingBy based on keys...)
```

I'm struggling with the syntax.

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: You can create nested Collector using recursion but I don't know how that will help you since it will collect as `Map<A,Map<B,Map<C....` Nested collector ex:  `Collector getNestedCollector(int pos, List<String> keys) { if (pos == keys.size() - 1) { return Collectors.groupingBy((Map map) -> map.get(keys.get(pos))); } else { return Collectors.groupingBy((Map map) -> map.get(keys.get(pos)), getNestedCollector(pos + 1, keys)); } }`

Comment: It works, this is exactly what I need. Thank you!